# Java's ProcessHandle cannot get arguments properly

Tags: java, processhandle

I have encountered into this problem while writing a minecraft mod.

Environment: MacOS
JVM:

```
java version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-LTS-86)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-LTS-86, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Reproduce:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ProcessHandle.current().info().commandLine().orElse("none"));
    }
}
```

Then execute this command:

```bash
java  "Main" "--username" "Steve47876" "--version" "1.20.1-fabric" "--gameDir" "/Users/zhaoliyan/Library/Application Support/minecraft/versions/1.20.1-fabric" "--assetsDir" "/Users/zhaoliyan/Library/Application Support/minecraft/assets" "--assetIndex" "5" "--uuid" "b7374a0acf0743e79a7a0e2cad64c9f9" "--accessToken" "eyJraWQiOiJhYzg07f3G03Vr3bhNG6vdsG7DD8QehRpITidVEZuo" "--clientId" "${clientid}" "--xuid" "${auth_xuid}" "--userType" "msa" "--versionType" "HMCL 3.5.5" "--width" "854" "--height" "480"
```

The output is "none".

**Update**: I found that if there is a `$` in arguments, java failed to get command line, e.g. `$a`, `${a}`. Is this a bug of java?

Comment: I think the reason commandLine() returns `Optional<String>` is precisely because some operating systems don’t provide a way to get the full command line for a process.

Answer (score 0):

According to ProcessHandle.Info's javadoc this class is implementation and platform specific. It does not garantee the results you expect.

Check this out:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessHandle.Info.html

Also check 'API Note' for commandLine() and argument() methods

If you're limited with OS choice you can try other vendors of jdks.

Btw your code works as expected in linux. I've checked it in docker container with Debian 12 and Corretto 11 jdk.

```
    root@29598b080453:/# cat >Main.java
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(ProcessHandle.current().info().commandLine());
        }
    }

    ^C
    root@29598b080453:/# javac Main.java
    root@29598b080453:/# java Main arg1 arg2
    Optional[/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/java Main arg1 arg2]
    root@29598b080453:/#
    root@29598b080453:/#
    root@29598b080453:/# java Main arg1 arg2 "agr3 with spaces"
    Optional[/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/java Main arg1 arg2 agr3 with spaces]
```

There are some examples of how $ character may affect command interpretation by shell and commandLine method output accordingly.

```
root@29598b080453:/# export arg2=arg2value
root@29598b080453:/# java Main arg1 arg2
Optional[/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/java Main arg1 arg2]
root@29598b080453:/# java Main arg1 '$arg2'
Optional[/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/java Main arg1 $arg2]
root@29598b080453:/# java Main arg1 "$arg2"
Optional[/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/java Main arg1 arg2value]
root@29598b080453:/# java Main arg1 '"$arg2"'
Optional[/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/java Main arg1 "$arg2"]
root@29598b080453:/# java Main arg1 "'$arg2'"
Optional[/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/java Main arg1 'arg2value']
root@29598b080453:/#
```

Comment: What if add a $ in the arguments? e.g.  java Main $test ?

Comment: '$' character on the command line could lead to 'parameter expansion, command substitution, or arithmetic expansion'. I'll update my answer to give you more examples.  Also see
[link](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)